# Is sql to Linq union by reference? (the same for except and intersect?)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, union, intersect

When you perform a union in linq to sql, will it be by reference - if the reference to the object point to the same object - or is it by the id field?

Example method:

```
        public IEnumerable<CustomerModel> GetCustomers(string searchCriteria)
    {
        ExpressLogger.LogDebug("Enter"); 
        try
        {
            var datacontext = Helpers.Utils.GetCustomerRmhDataContext();
            using(datacontext)
            {
               var accountCustomers = datacontext.Customers.Where(c => 
                            c.AccountNumber.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteria.ToLower())).Select(c=>convertRmhToModel(c,datacontext)).ToList();

                var phoneCustomers = datacontext.Customers.Where(c =>
                            c.PhoneNumber.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteria.ToLower())).Select(c => convertRmhToModel(c, datacontext)).ToList();

                var personalNumberCustomers = datacontext.Customers.Where(c =>
                            c.TaxNumber.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteria.ToLower())).Select(c => convertRmhToModel(c, datacontext)).ToList();

                var emailCustomers = datacontext.Customers.Where(c =>
                            c.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(searchCriteria.ToLower())).Select(c => convertRmhToModel(c, datacontext)).ToList();


                var allCustomers = accountCustomers.Union(phoneCustomers).Union(personalNumberCustomers).Union(emailCustomers).ToList();


                return allCustomers;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExpressLogger.LogError(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This function do what i want, it searches for customer for accountnumber, phone, mail and swedish personalnumber. And then i make a union and return the result. But im curios - how does this work, will it compare the union with the ID field or is it by reference - will it check hashcode and equal comparer? (is it the same for intersect and except?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, `.Union` is called on .Net collections and its behavior is defined in the docs for [`Enumerable.Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netframework-4.8):

> The default equality comparer, [Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?view=netframework-4.8), is used to compare values of the types that implement the IEqualityComparer generic interface.

This is further clarified in the docs for [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?view=netframework-4.8):

> The Default property checks whether type `T` implements the [`System.IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface and, if so, returns an [`EqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an [`EqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) that uses the overrides of [`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Object.GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8) provided by `T`.

So, if `CustomerModel` implements [`IEquatable<CustomerModel>.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals?view=netframework-4.8) and/or overrides `Object.Equals`, then `Union` uses one of these methods to compare customers.

Otherwise, it falls back on default implementation of [`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8) that compares object references:

> If the current instance is a reference type, the `Equals(Object)` method tests for reference equality, and a call to the `Equals(Object)` method is equivalent to a call to the `ReferenceEquals` method..